# State is changing but datatable not showing new data

Tags: reactjs, datatable, mui-datatable

I am working with **material-ui** library and making datatables. For datatable, I am using this library [mui-datatables](https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables). I need to call an API to retrieve data and show in the table. I checked in the console that data is coming but not showing in datatable.

Below is my code:

```
state = {
    students: [],
    rows: []
};

componentDidMount() {
    document.title = "List of students";

    axios
        .get("api.url")
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({ students: res.data }, () => {
                this.state.students.forEach((value, index) => {
                    this.state.rows.push({
                        digitalcredid: value.studentid,
                        firstname: value.firstname,
                        lastname: value.lastname,
                        email: value.email,
                        nationality: value.nationality,
                        postaladress: value.postaladress,
                        nic: value.nic
                    });
                });
            });
        });
}
```

and showing data like below:

```
const options = {
     filterType: "checkbox",
     serverSide: true,
     print: false
};

<div className="row">
     <div className="col-12">
          <MUIDataTable
               title={"Student List"}
               data={this.state.rows}
               columns={studentColumns}
               options={options}
            />
      </div>
 </div>
```

It would be great if someone help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are directly mutating the state to update `rows` instead of calling `setState`, hence the re-render is not triggered. Try this :

```
componentDidMount() {
    document.title = "List of students";

    axios.get("api.url").then(res => {
      const rows = [];

      res.data.forEach((value, index) => {
        rows.push({
          digitalcredid: value.studentid,
          firstname: value.firstname,
          lastname: value.lastname,
          email: value.email,
          nationality: value.nationality,
          postaladress: value.postaladress,
          nic: value.nic
        });
      });

      this.setState({ students: res.data, rows });
    });
  }
```

From React [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> setState() enqueues changes to the component state and tells React
>   that this component and its children need to be re-rendered with the
>   updated state.

`state` can also be mutated directly like you did above. But that will not trigger a re-render. Hence always update state with `setState` if you need the fresh data to be displayed.

Comment: It's working as expected. Thanks a lot! Actually, I always do it in the way I mentioned.